# replacing specific elements of a vector

Tags: r

I am trying to make a user-defined function below using the R

```
wrkexpcode.into.month <- function(vec) {
  tmp.vec <- vec
  tmp.vec[tmp.vec == 0 | tmp.vec == 9] <- NA
  tmp.vec[tmp.vec == 1] <- 4
  tmp.vec[tmp.vec == 2] <- 13
  tmp.vec[tmp.vec == 3] <- 31
  tmp.vec[tmp.vec == 4] <- 78
  tmp.vec[tmp.vec == 5] <- 174
  tmp.vec[tmp.vec == 6] <- 240

  return (tmp.vec)
}
```

but when I execute with a simple command like

```
wrkexpcode.into.month(c(3,2,2,3,1,3,5,6,4))
```

the result comes like

```
[1]  31  13  13  31  78  31 174 240  78
```

but I expect the result like

```
[1]  31  13  13  31  **4**  31 174 240  78
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's doing what you told it to do. After replacing 1 with 4, you tell it to replace 4 with 78. Replace `[tmp.vec == x]` with `[vec == x]`.

Comment: BTW this can be done much more easily using `switch`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft or just with subsetting

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to carefully follow the flow of your function, evaluating what the values are. You are expecting `1` to be replaced by `4` based on `tmp.vec[tmp.vec == 1] <- 4`, however in `tmp.vec[tmp.vec == 4] <- 78` later down the road, the `4` is replaced by a `78`. This is caused by replacing the values in `tmp.vec` and using `tmp.vec` for determining what needs to be replaced. Like @MattewPlourde said, you need to base the replacement on `vec`:

```
tmp.vec[vec == 1] <- 4
```

Although I would simply replace the code by:

```
wrkexpcode.into.month <- function(vec) {
    translation_vector = c('0' = NA, '1' = 4, '2' = 13, '3' = 31, 
                           '4' = 78, '5' = 174, '6' = 240, '9' = NA)
    return(translation_vector[as.character(vec)])
}
wrkexpcode.into.month(c(3,2,2,3,1,3,5,6,4))
#   3   2   2   3   1   3   5   6   4 
#  31  13  13  31   4  31 174 240  78
```

See also a blogpost [I wrote recently](http://www.numbertheory.nl/2014/01/25/vectorisation-is-your-best-friend-replacing-many-elements-in-a-character-vector/) about this kind of operation.

Comment: Why use character subsetting here?

Comment: @hadley I cannot use normal subsetting as there is a possibility for a  `0`, which is not possible with an index. Effectively I treat the input numbers as character keys.

Comment: Ah, that would be easier to see if you used names in the first call to c

Comment: It definitely makes the code a bit arcane to read, I changed the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

It think it will be much easier to use one of the many `recode` functions that are designed for such purposes instead of hard-coding it. It's just a one-liner then, e.g.

```
library(likert)
x <- c(3,2,2,3,1,3,5,6,4)

recode(x, from=c(0:6, 9), to=c(NA, 4,13,31,78,174,240,NA))
[1] 31  13  13  31   4  31 174 240  78
```

And if desired, wrap it into a function, e.g.

```
wrkexpcode.into.month <- function(x)
  recode(x, from=c(0:6, 9), to=c(NA, 4,13,31,78,174,240,NA))

wrkexpcode.into.month(x)
[1] 31  13  13  31   4  31 174 240  78
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create matrix pointing the input value (column1) to the desired output value (column2)

```
table=matrix(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,9,NA,4,13,31,78,174,240,NA),ncol=2)
```

And using sapply on the vector `c(3,2,2,3,1,3,5,6,4)`

```
 sapply(c(3,2,2,3,1,3,5,6,4), function(x) table[which(table[,1] == x),2] )
```

to give you the desired output too